# Can't get my armature to move other meshes along with the main character model

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I'm a Blender novice. What I want to do is upload a model to Mixamo, download it with animation, and then export that animation from Blender as an animated obj sequence so I can use it in After Effects Element 3D.

The model I want to use isn't rigged, and the a-pose is a little funky so Mixamo doesn't do a great job rigging automatically. I created a simple armature and attached the body to it. The problem is that there's some objects that are separate meshes attached to the body - clothes, eyes, hair, etc. These meshes are not moving when I pose the armature. I've tried parenting these meshes to the body mesh, and I've tried parenting them to the armature. Neither seems to be working. Could some wise guru [look at my project file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvpa6czr2g5daqk/Lola%209-15a.blend?dl=0) and tell me how to set this up so I can upload the model to Mixamo and have all the pieces where they're supposed to be? Thanks!

Comment: for example for the hair: select the hair object, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select the head bone, then ctrl P > Bone, and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got the pieces to move with the armature, but now my problem is that the clothes are clipping:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7338wiujiht4kwc/clipping%20example.png?dl=0

Comment: you need to give some corrections to the cloth in Weight Paint mode, select the armature, shift select the cloth, switch to Weight Paint mode, select a bone then see what weight it has and give some corrections (in the tool settings, disable Front Face Only, Front-face Falloff, enable Falloff Shape > Projected. Maybe follow some tutorials on this matter, a bit hard to explain the whole thing   ;)

Comment: I guess even a basic armature isn't always so basic! I've been doing After Effects for years and this 3D stuff is a whole 'nother level of hard. Thanks for the tips.